# How to get or combine values in an array of objects based on index, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, for-loop

I have a collection from MongoDB that I stored in an array using foreach. I need to loop through the array and have it output like below. The members object should properly be associated with the "lead" field (i.e. based on index I think).

- Index 0: Josh, Person A 50, Person B 100
- Index 1: Carl, Person A 25, Person B 50, Person C 75

I used for loop and I got this result, but I'm not sure what to do next. Should I use another loop?

```
0: {lead: 'Josh', treasure: Array(2)}
1: {lead: 'Carl', treasure: Array(3)}
```

Here's the returned result from a MongoDB collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "0001",
    "lead": "Josh",
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "Person A",
        "points": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "Person B",
        "points": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "0002",
    "lead": "Carl",
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "Person A",
        "points": 25
      },
      {
        "name": "Person B",
        "points": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "Person C",
        "points": 75
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here's my for loop so far:

```
let group = [];
let combination = [];
mongodb.query.foreach((result) => group.push(result))
for (i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    group[i] = { lead: group[i].lead, members: group[i].members };
}
console.log(group);
```

I tried using 2 for loops but it's creating a new index for each member:

```
for (i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
  for (x = 0; x < group[i].length; x++) {
    group[i] = { lead: group[i].lead, name: group[i].members[x].name, points: group[i].members[x].points };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const queryResult = [
  {
    "_id": "0001",
    "lead": "Josh",
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "Person A",
        "points": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "Person B",
        "points": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "0002",
    "lead": "Carl",
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "Person A",
        "points": 25
      },
      {
        "name": "Person B",
        "points": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "Person C",
        "points": 75
      }
    ]
  }
];

const group = queryResult.map(({ lead, members }) =>
  [lead, ...members.map(({ name, points }) => `${name} ${points}`)].join(", ")
);

console.log(group);
```

Explanation:

1. `queryResult.map(({ lead, members }) => ...` - [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with some [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for easy access.
2. `` [lead, ...members.map(({ name, points }) => `${name} ${points}`)] `` - creating array with `lead` on index `0`. Using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...members` to get each member added after `lead`. Getting each member name and points as string with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `` members.map(({ name, points }) => `${name} ${points}`) ``
3. Create string from array with [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) `.join(", ")`

Comment: This worked. Although could you explain a bit how this one exactly works? Thanks